# C++ DirectX: С чего начать?

Tags: c++, directx

Недавно появилось сильное желание погрузится в изучение DirectX, по итогу этого изучения хотелось бы написать какую-нибудь простенькую игрушку. Проблема в том, что никак не могу найти толковых гайдов, уроков по этой теме на просторах сети, может кто уже сталкивался с этой проблемой и может помочь советом, с чего начать?

Comment: Может книгу, а не "гайды в интернетах"?

Comment: Скачайте DirectX SDK (или с microsoft или более раннии версии они проще, из других источников), там есть 1. справка по функциям, 2. несколько рабочих примеров на разную тематику.

Comment: http://www.rastertek.com/tutindex.html, предварительно необходимы твердые знания C/C++, COM и линал.

Comment: Выбирая DirectX, Вы заранее отрубаете практически ВСЕ платформы кроме Windows.
Я бы посоветовал OpenGL, конкретно OpenGL ES 3.2.
Он работает просто везде. Писать можно тоже много на чем, включая C++.
Свой собственный опыт я постарался изложить тут:
[https://writingagame.ru/](https://writingagame.ru/)
Это блог/обучалка по: GameDev, 3D, cross-platform, C++, Visual Studio, Android, Windows, OpenGL ES, бесплатно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

сам читаю  книгу "[DirectX 10 - это просто. Програмируем графику на С++](http://www.bhv.ru/books/book.php?id=182868) ", замечу её дружелюбие и не большие отличия от DirectX 11 , по сути как **базис вообще отменна**, **объяснение кода** , **отличные примеры**, также **прекрасный русский язык**.

Также есть достаточно фундаментальный труд [luna frank D](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=iXz&channel=fs&ei=7VooXqH8M-XamwXK8YuQBQ&q=luna%20frank%20D&oq=luna%20frank%20D&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i10i30j0i22i30l5.1122990.1130540..1131018...0.5..0.99.945.12......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i10j0j0i67j0i131i67j0i131j0i19j0i22i30i19.cPmy7ppnEks&ved=0ahUKEwjhpt-rtJfnAhVl7aYKHcr4AlIQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) для каждого DirectX начиная с DirectX 8 она пишет книги.

*Также надо понимать что после освоения этих книг многие уходят в усиленное изучение шейдеров ([от ДМК-пресс неплохие книги есть](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/978-5-97060-255-3/)), ландшафтов(3D-ланшафты Грег Снук) и т.д.*

Таже замечу что **архитектура** написания графической программы что на DirectX 10, что на DirectX 11, что на DirectX 12 **не отличается**.Это важно !!